# WCF: The server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on this problem quiet a long time... next step would be to reinstall all my PCs and/or reprogram everything...

The program(C#) I'm using is an old one (the guy who wrote this isn't available anymore :( )

Everything works fine on another testenvironment, but not on mine... we were not able to figure out where the differences are.

When I start my program and try to connect to my client I get an error:

> The server has rejected the client credentials.

What I did by now:

- Tried it with the preconfigured Administrator User.
- I created the same user on both PCs, which are in the same Workgroup
  User: Test      PW: 123456      WorkGroup: TESTLAB
- I added in the Local Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Access this computer from the network the Users: Everyone, Authenticated User, Administrator (on both PCs)
- Windows Firewall is disabled, both PCs can ping each other and can connect via RDP

I also see some network packages flying arround while trying to connect (with Wireshark)

```
    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding getLargeNetTCPTransferBinding()
    {
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(/*SecurityMode.Message, true*/);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 2, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 2, 0);
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        //binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        //binding.TransactionFlow = true;
        return binding;
    }
```

as I said, the same code works in another testenvironment :/
also the communictaion works with "localhost", so at least the code "should" work also on my workstations.
Both PCs are running Windows XP SP3 (the same as on the second environment where everything works)

Hopefully someone can help me :/

Comment: Just a trite observation, but if the code works elsewhere, you may need to review configuration.

Comment: You are using `SecurityMode.Transport`, are the same certificates installed on both PCs ?

Comment: @Mark: First of all thanks! that's a small problem the second configuration is about 1000km away from here. The admin/developer told me that it is a simple Windows XP Sp3 installation with VS2010 (same as i have :/)

Comment: @Henk: sry I'm really new at WCF and all i know is from MSDN (not very much by now) but what do you mean with this certificate? do I have to install a special one? I thought this means that Windows User/PW is used for authentication :/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure a cert is used but a self-signed cert at the server would explain this difference. It would have been manually accepted as 'trusted' on the working PC.

Comment: Check the time between the client and server. If its off more than 5 minutes, the server will reject the client requests. 5 minutes is the default and can be adjusted in the server configuration.

Comment: @user957902: I think that changed something, there was a small time difference, but now I get another Error _"A remote side security requirement was not fulfilled during authentication. Try increasing the ProtectionLevel and/or ImpersonationLevel."_ As I wrote before my ProtectionLevel is `ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign`, so there is no higher level...

Comment: no, didn't change anything :/ still stuck with the same error message

Comment: So, as we found out by today there is a problem with our PCs. WCF seems to work on "older" PCs but not on our new once... by now we couldn't figure out where the problem is, but as we need to get this up and running also on our new PCs we will work on a solution